# Edit GoogleDocs documents in UltraEdit or Notepad++?

Tags: google-docs

I would like to edit GoogleDocs documents in UltraEdit or Notepad++.
Reason being a few features missing from the current GoogleDocs editor.

Can this be done ?

---

My use-case:
I log my work in a logfile.txt
UltraEdit and other native editors are lightning fast and have column editing, excellent search result display, macros and other power user features, not available in GDocs yet.

I would like to keep working in UltraEdit until those features are available, but at the same time have the document synced in the background to GDocs.

So, Nocs doesn't cut if for me yet (until it has the same featureset and speed of ex. UltraEdit),
however the sync stuff you have implemented is interesting, if you could somehow add this as a plugin to UltraEdit and other editors. At least some of them have a plugin architecture.

Another "feature" of GDocs that has currently stopped me from using this approach, is the 512kB document size limit.

Comment: if it's source code you're editing, gdocs is not a great collaborative repository.  There are free providers of subversion or git repositories which you would find much easier to integrate with (and collaberate).

Comment: https://bespin.mozilla.com/ is also an option depending on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it "in place" as it were.

You can export the doc from gdocs, edit, and reimport.  in the menu at the top of the Google Doc: File -> Download File As -> Text, edit away in your favourite editor, then File -> Upload New Version (you can do this for spreahsheets anyway, not sure if this is available for every format, you might need to create a new doc and delete the old one)

Answer (score 0):

You have to export it as a rich text document, then edit it in notepad++, then import it back to google docs.

Don't expect this question to live long as it's unrelated to programming.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a shameless plug here, but if you want simple, Notepad-like functionality that integrates with Google Docs, you can check my project called [Nocs](http://nocs.googlecode.com/).